# Issues passing a variable to a function

Tags: c, parameter-passing

I wrote a few lines of code for a function that will replace all spaces in a string with "-" and print the string. The code compiles, but when it runs, it prints "New string is   with 0 replacements". Would anybody please be able to tell me where my code is going wrong? I'm assuming it has something to do with the way the char is passed to the function.

```
//Ben Adamson
//v1.0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void replace(char s)
{
    int num = 0;
    while (s != '\0')
    {
        if (s == ' ')
        {
            s = "-";
            num++;
        }
        s++;
    }
    printf("New string is %c with %d replacements", s, num);
}

int main()
{
    char str = "The cat sat";
    replace(str);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: String literals can't be modified. Use `char str[] = "The cat sat";` instead. (Assuming you mean `char str = "The cat sat";` by `char *str = "The cat sat";` )

Comment: Thanks haccks, that set me in the right direction. I worked out the full solution below.

Comment: This code has several compilation errors and warnings!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a way to solve all of my code's issues. Please see code below:

```
//Ben Adamson
//v1.0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void replace(char *s);

int main()
{
    char str[] = "The cat sat";
    replace(str);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void replace(char *s)
{
    int num = 0;
    unsigned int i;

    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ')
        {
            s[i] = 45;
            num++;
        }
    }

    printf("New string is %s with %d replacements", s, num);
}
```

Comment: For the sake of readability, I suggest you either replace `45` for `'-'` , or add a comment `/* dash sign */ `

Comment: Also at the beginning, right before the `for` loop, you may want to make sure s is valid : `if(!s) return ;`

Comment: Your code is fine but it can be twice faster. C strings are terminated with a zero ; the `strlen` function counts how many characters are there by going through the string until it finds a zero. Then you have your `for` loop. So you are actually scanning your string twice. You can scan it only once if instead of a `for` you used a `while(s[i]!=0)`

Comment: Thanks Gui, I will take that into account.